# Elasticsearch fail to start shards

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin, elastica

I am trying to fix my shards with the following command

```
java -cp lucene-core-4.10.2.jar -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/XXX/0/index/ -fix
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex
```

Comment: It probably isn't finding lucene-core-4.10.2.jar .  Try specifying a full, absolute path to the jar, see if that works.

Comment: Any idea where do I find the lucene-core-4.10.2.jar

Comment: You can download it from http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/java/

Comment: Additionally, if you absolutely need to, you can have Elasticsearch do this upon startup by setting the `index.shard.check_on_startup: fix` setting in elasticsearch.yml

Comment: will it work because in current document they mentioned "The same as false. This option is deprecated and will be completely removed in 7.0."   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#_static_index_settings

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this command from the jars directory. They are at /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib in my ubuntu distribution.

Comment: How about Windows?